# Max returning all values on a self join

Tags: sql, plsql

My problem requires me to query data from the table, and include a column to calculate the % increase as well. I need to pull only the records with the highest % of increase using MAX. I think I'm on the right track but but for some reason its returning all records despite the having clause calling for just the max.

```
Select
  O.Grocery_Item,
  TO_CHAR(sum(g.Price_IN_2000), '$99,990.00') TOTAL_IN_2000,
  TO_CHAR(sum(g.Estimated_Price_In_2025), '$99,990.00') TOTAL_IN_2025,
  TO_CHAR(Round(O.MY_OUTPUT),'9,990') || '%' as My_Output
From
  GROCERY_PRICES g,
  (SELECT
     GROCERY_ITEM,
     (((sum(Estimated_Price_In_2025) -
        sum(Price_IN_2000))/sum(Price_IN_2000))*100) MY_OUTPUT
   FROM
     GROCERY_PRICES
   GROUP BY GROCERY_ITEM) O
Where
  G.GROCERY_ITEM = O.GROCERY_ITEM 
GROUP BY
  O.GROCERY_ITEM, O.MY_OUTPUT
Having
  my_output IN (select Max(O.MY_OUTPUT) from GROCERY_PRICES);
```

Results:

```
GROCERY_ITEM                   TOTAL_IN_2000 TOTAL_IN_2025 MY_OUTPUT
------------------------------ ------------- ------------- ---------
M_004                                $2.70         $5.65      109%   
B_001                                $0.80         $2.64      230%   
T_006                                $5.70         $6.65       17%   
B_002                                $2.72         $7.36      171%   
E_001                                $0.62         $1.78      187%   
R_003                                $4.00        $13.20      230%   

 6 rows selected
```

Comment: Since your group by is on item the output max is also by item.  If you want to only lsit the single highest % item you'll likely have to do a sub select OR, order by my_output limiting output to 1 record

Comment: I don't think that this line would be legit: `select Max(O.MY_OUTPUT)`, referencing `O.MY_OUTPUT` and querying it from `GROCERY_PRICES`

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately ordering it doesn't seem to be helping. Also, the 'Select MAX(O.MY_output) was just an error, but it isn't influencing the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your query so you only select from the Groceries table once since your `My_Output` column is only a function of numbers you are already producing the self join is not necessary. Then I've used RANK to get the top records (although if you are not concerned about ties ROWNUM will work better):

```
SELECT  g.Grocery_Item,
        g.TOTAL_IN_2000,
        g.TOTAL_IN_2025,
        g.My_Output
FROM    (   SELECT  Grocery_Item,
                    TO_CHAR(TOTAL_IN_2000, '$99,990.00') TOTAL_IN_2000,
                    TO_CHAR(TOTAL_IN_2025, '$99,990.00') TOTAL_IN_2025,
                    TO_CHAR(ROUND(((TOTAL_IN_2025 / TOTAL_IN_2000) - 1) * 100), '9,990') || '%' as My_Output,
                    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Grocery_Item ORDER BY (TOTAL_IN_2025 / TOTAL_IN_2000) - 1 DESC) AS GroceryRank
            FROM    (   SELECT  g.Grocery_Item,
                                SUM(g.Price_IN_2000) TOTAL_IN_2000,
                                SUM(g.Estimated_Price_In_2025) TOTAL_IN_2025
                        FROM    GROCERY_PRICES g
                        GROUP BY g.Grocery_Item
                    ) g
        ) g
WHERE   GroceryRank = 1;
```

I've also simplified your percentage calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
select *
from (Select O.Grocery_Item, TO_CHAR(sum(g.Price_IN_2000), '$99,990.00') TOTAL_IN_2000,
             TO_CHAR(sum(g.Estimated_Price_In_2025), '$99,990.00') TOTAL_IN_2025,
             TO_CHAR(Round(O.MY_OUTPUT),'9,990') || '%' as My_Output
      From GROCERY_PRICES g join
           (SELECT GROCERY_ITEM,
                   (((sum(Estimated_Price_In_2025) -
                    sum(Price_IN_2000))/sum(Price_IN_2000))*100
                    ) MY_OUTPUT
            FROM GROCERY_PRICES
            GROUP BY GROCERY_ITEM
           ) O
           on G.GROCERY_ITEM = O.GROCERY_ITEM 
      GROUP BY O.GROCERY_ITEM, O.MY_OUTPUT
      ORDER BY my_output desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1
```

The problem is that your subquery only has outer references.  So, the `o.my_output` is coming from the outer table, not the `from` clause in the subquery.  You are comparing a value to itself, which for non-NULL values is always true.

Since you want the maximum value, the easiest way is to order the list and take the first row.  You can also do this with analytic functions, but rownum is usually more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the query kicked back 17% which is the MIN. should I change the 1 to satisfiy the MAX?

Comment: I edited the query to add the `desc` in the `order by`.  Just add that in.

Comment: Thanks again, your suggestion worked when i adjusted it, however I need to pull all records at MAX. In this case there are 2. Still trying to get my head around your explanation of the self referencing part ( I'm a rookie)